# How can i make datatable empty before using filters?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

```
 var dataTable = $('#timesheetTable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'searching': false, // Set false to remove default Search Control
            'ajax': {
                'url': 'timesheet_fetch.php',
                'data': function(data) {
                    data.name = window.name;
                }
            },
            'columns': [
                {data: 'start_timestamp'}, 
                {data: 'end_timestamp'},
                {data: 'duration'},
                {data: 'activity'},
                {data: 'description'},
                {data: 'name'},
                {data: 'bogie_serial_no'},
            ]
        });

        $('.name').click(function() {
           dataTable.draw();
        });
```

I have code to view data table, by pressing multiple buttons, the data table can be filtered by name.

I want to only view the data table by filter, and if no filter is clicked, I want the dateable to not be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dataTable.clear()`

Please be aware that this method will not automatically redraw the table with an empty data set. In order to redraw the table use the `draw()` method, which can be called simply as a chained method of the `clear()` method's returned object - for example `table.clear().draw();`.

This is useful for performance when you would want to immediately add new rows to the table - you would only call the `draw()` method once all required rows have been added to help improve performance.

Comment: `dataTable.clear()` should not be used when `serverSide` is set to `true` https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()